# Como validar uma regra regex para uma citação de usuario?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou fazendo um funcionalidade no meu site para citar usuários usando `@`:

```
@bananinha disse aquilo
```

No caso o nome `@bananinha` vai se transforma em um link quando a pessoa submeter o comentário. Consigo fazer com um monte de `if` essa validação porém vi que com regex o código fica mais clean.

No caso estou fazendo com regex porém não estou conseguindo pegar todas os casos.

As regras que precisa atender é:

- O primeiro caractere deve ser `@`
- O restante dos caracteres devem ser `A-Z`, `a-z`, `.` , ou , `_`. E deve conter pelo menos un caractere.
- O caractere `@` deve aparecer apenas uma única vez.

O que tenho até agora é essa regra:

```js
function validNickname(str) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('[@][A-Za-z0-9._]','i');
    return !!pattern.test(str);
  }


  function getMention(str) {
    var words = str.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
      console.log(words[i], validNickname(words[i]));
    }
  }
  
  t = '@ @@@@ @bananinha oloco@meu cachorrinho@ @nick_fury @pik4chu @$$money_ @estou_entre_arrobas@ @estou_entre_arrobas@eu_tambem@'
  
  getMention(t);
```

Porém tem alguns casos que não estou conseguindo validar, como primeira e única ocorrência do `@`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta trocar para:

```js
function validNickname(str) {
    let pattern = /^@[A-Za-z0-9._]+$/;
    return pattern.test(str);
}

function getMention(str) {
    str.split(' ')
       .forEach(word => console.log(word, validNickname(word)));
}
  
let t = '@ @@@@ @bananinha oloco@meu cachorrinho@ @nick_fury @pik4chu @$$money_ @estou_entre_arrobas@ @estou_entre_arrobas@eu_tambem@';
  
getMention(t);
```

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim você garante que a regex vai verificar todo o conteúdo da string, além de deixar claro que a `@` só pode estar no início.

O trecho `[A-Za-z0-9._]` é uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), que corresponde a qualquer letra de `A` a `Z` (maiúsculas ou minúsculas), dígitos de 0 a 9, ponto ou `_`. O detalhe é que toda essa expressão corresponde a apenas **um** caractere. Ou seja, a sua regex só verificava se tinha um caractere depois da `@`, desconsiderando o restante da string.

Para considerar mais de um caractere, usei o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências), para indicar que as letras, ponto e `_` podem se repetir várias vezes. E o `$` garante que só pode ter esses caracteres até o final da string.

Repare que a [*flag* `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) não é necessária. Ela indica que a regex deve ser *case insensitive*, mas como você já usou `A-Za-z`, a regex já vai considerar tanto as letras maiúsculas quanto as minúsculas.

Também troquei `[@]` por apenas `@`, já que os colchetes não fazem diferença nesse caso (ambas as expressões são equivalentes).

Por fim, o [método `test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) já [retorna um *booleano*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Returns), não precisa fazer `!!` no retorno do método.

---

Outra opção é usar:

```js
let pattern = /^@[\w.]+$/;
  
let t = '@ @@@@ @bananinha oloco@meu cachorrinho@ @nick_fury @pik4chu @$$money_ @estou_entre_arrobas@ @estou_entre_arrobas@eu_tambem@';
  
t.split(' ').forEach(word => console.log(word, pattern.test(word)));
```

Pois o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` já considera as letras, números o o caractere `_`.

---

Vale lembrar que essas regex são "ingênuas", pois aceitam strings como `@_._...`, por exemplo (pois todos os caracteres contidos em `[A-Za-z0-9._]` podem se repetir várias vezes - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/U0Y2Kb/1/)):

```js
let pattern = /^@[\w.]+$/;
  
let t = '@__._... @___abc.123....';
  
t.split(' ').forEach(word => console.log(word, pattern.test(word)));
```

Se quiser ser mais específico, a regex fica um pouco mais complicada. Por exemplo, se o critério for que ponto e o `_` não podem aparecer mais de uma vez seguida (`@abc.123` pode, mas `@abc..123` e `@abc._123` não), uma opção seria:

```js
let pattern = /^@[A-Za-z0-9]+([._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/;
  
let t = '@__._... @___abc.123.... @abc.123_xyz @abc._123';
  
t.split(' ').forEach(word => console.log(word, pattern.test(word)));
```

Repare que agora a classe de caracteres `[A-Za-z0-9]` só tem as letras e números. Em seguida, há um trecho contendo `[._]` (um ponto ou `_`) seguido de uma ou mais letras/dígitos. Esse trecho final está agrupado entre parênteses, e o quantificador `*` indica que ele pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes. Ou seja, a sequência "ponto ou `_`, seguido de letras/dígitos" pode se repetir várias vezes (para casos como `@abc.123_xyz`), ou nenhuma (para os casos como `@abc123`).

Enfim, regex é assim mesmo: quanto mais específica e quanto mais casos quiser tratar, mais complexa ela vai ficando. Cabe a você escolher até onde ir (se você sabe que nunca terão casos como `@abc....123`, por exemplo, pode usar a primeira versão mesmo).